# How suffixes like -ness and -ship are chosen when forming abstract nouns?

Tags: expression-choice, word-formation, identifier-choice

In some programming situations I came across making up abstract nouns to give name to an information that indicates some quality. Eg. if the quality is `orange` one may be tempted to form the word `orangeness`.

I found several possible postfixes for this in [a paper by Dr. Suneetha Yedla](http://www.ijhssi.org/papers/v2%283%29/version-5/B230914.pdf):

```
ii) Forming abstract nouns
-asy, -acy “state or quality” accuracy
-age “condition, state, rank, office of” coinage, postage, barrage
-ance, -ence “state, act, fact of” emergence
-ade “general noun” salad, parade, lemonade
-al “act of” chemical, mechanical, physical, structural, operational
-ation “state of being X-ed” information, aviation, configuration, validation
-ia “condition of” inertia
-ial “differential, industrial
-icity “abstract noun from – ic” felicity, electricity
-ism “doctrical system of principles” constructivism, professionalism
-ity “state, quality, condition of” unity, complexity, solidity, fragility
-ment “condition of being X” equipment, experiment, requirement
-ness “state, quality, condition of” innateness, thickness
-ship “state, condition of” guide ship, airship, (large) cruise ship
```

The descriptions in the list are not exactly distinct.
Suppose one cannot say which one 'feels right', I am not native; how do one choose the right suffix?

Comment: salad is a construct as an abstract noun?

Comment: This is an impressive, interesting, and I'd say useful article (hence +1), naxa. But please don't expect English to be totally predictable, consistent or logical. You can check a Google count and a few examples for guessed / dubious words like 'orangeness', if you can't find the ones you want / suspect, in a dictionary (though this one actually _is_). 'Orangity' appears on the internet also, but appears to be a whimsical coinage.

Comment: [Derivational suffixes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Inflection.pdf) like these are not "chosen". They just happen to be the ones that got stuck on and don't come unglued over time, which is largely an accidental matter. That's why their meanings are (to put it mildly) "not exactly distinct". In fact, meaning has practically nothing to do with the choice; it's determined by the root, not the meaning.

Comment: The examples for '-ship' look wrong to me; I'd expect words such as 'hardship', 'internship' or 'citizenship' there, not varieties of actual ships.

Comment: What @John said. Doubtless many suffix usages fall into "patterns", but the entire question is Too Broad to be meaningfully and adequately dealt with here.

Comment: EdwinAshworth and JohnLawler, yes I was amazed too to find this work. I see your points, but wasn't sure of how free it is, previously. (In particular I considered ease of pronunciation, or etymological reasons.) I think your comments are good as answers as well.

Comment: @yatima Many of the examples are etymologically questionable (or outright bogus). Still an interesting question, though!

Comment: I don't think **salad** is derived from sal (salt) + 'ade'....

Comment: @Oldcat [Salad etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=salad&allowed_in_frame=0)

Answer (score 3):

There is no system in wordformation with suffixes. It is mostly a matter from which language the suffixed words are taken. A great percentage of these words were taken 
from Latin, and Latin already had a highly developed system of prefixes and suffixes. The other words where taken from French wtih the French suffixes.
So it is almost impossible to predict which suffix a word will have. Of course you will find subsystems,eg the nouns with -ness are almost all formed from adjectives,
but it is not warm *warmness but warmth, and it is not cold *coldness, but cold adj and  cold noun. Wordformation is a vast and unsystematic area. 
I have a reference work on this matter - Hans Marchand, The Categories and Types of
Present-Day English Word-Formation, Beck München 1969-2, 545 pages. I must say I seldom  use it, now and then I look up a special affix, but the book is not really
important for me.

Answer (score 1):

English is a very irregular language, certainly made more so by the number of words that come from other [languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_language_influences_in_English) (e.g [loanwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword) and [Calques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque))

I would suggest using a English dictionary (or word list, if your program is doing the parsing), to look up the root word, to see if there is an established word that matches your pattern.  This will take care of the normal expressions.

For [neologisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism#Science_and_technology), (i.e.the ones that don't exist in the dictionary or word list), I do not know of a way to generate them automatically so they sound valid.  I am sure some linguist can uncover some arcane grammatical rule which can be applied.